# python: boto3 _send_request() error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to user boto3 within docker but this error: `TypeError: _send_request() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given` always responds to me. For example:

Out the docker:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

And everything works, but within docker python interpreter, it gives me the error.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/h5Lf28Tn

Comment: Is this 3.6? There's a known bug: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1079

Comment: Oh, I did not know. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

you can upgrade your boto3 and will fix it:
pip install --upgrade boto3

Comment: the upgrade didn't influence for me, still got this issue

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade boto3 using: pip install --upgrade boto3 and restart the runtime environment.
This works for me.